# How do I make an image appear on desktops and tablets, but not on phones, using bootstrap?

Tags: html, css, image, twitter-bootstrap, background

I am working on a small project of mine.
It's a website for booking tours.
I'm still in the early stages, but this is what it looks like:
[homepage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k5Fxk.png)

As you can see, each tour has his own "div" divided in 3 columns: A preview image, a short description and a button to book the tour.
I can easily add an image as a background, but if I shrink the page to a size like that from a mobile, a second div appears above the first one with the image in it, like this:
[homepage mobile size](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cPnbB.png)

I have no idea why this occurs. Do any of you have any idea how to make the div for the image disappear on mobile or how to solve this problem?
HTML and CSS code is provided below, I am using bootstrap.

PS: Ignore the white-space around the button.

```css
body {
 margin: 0px;
 padding: 0px;
}

.jumbotron {
 border-radius: 0px;
 margin-bottom: 0px;
}

.options {
 margin-top: 30px;
}

.tours {
 padding: 0px;
 margin-bottom: 25px;
 border-radius: 5px;
 border: 1px solid grey;
 max-width: 100%;
 height: 20vh;
}

.preview-img {
 height: 100%;
}

.short-descr {
 padding-top: 2vh;
 height: 100%;
 background-color: red;
}

.more-info {
 height: 100%;
 padding: 0px;
}

.infobtn {
 height: 100%;
 width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <title>home</title>
 <meta charset="utf-8" name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-hwg4gsxgFZhOsEEamdOYGBf13FyQuiTwlAQgxVSNgt4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js" integrity="sha256-VazP97ZCwtekAsvgPBSUwPFKdrwD3unUfSGVYrahUqU=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
 <script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.css">
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/datepicker.css">
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/homepage-style.css">
</head>
<body>

 <!--Jumbotron, header for the website-->
 <div class="jumbotron text-center">

  <div class="container">
   <h1>Title</h1>
   <p>Description</p>
  </div>

 </div>

 <!--These are the columns in which the tours are displayed-->
 <div class="container options">
  
  <div class="col-xs-12 tours">

   <div class="col-sm-3 preview-img">

   </div>

   <div class="col-xs-9 col-sm-7 short-descr">
    <h4 class="text-left">Column 1</h4>
    <p class="text-left">Lorem Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet...</p>
   </div>

   <div class="col-xs-3 col-sm-2 more-info">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-info infobtn" href="#">More</button>
   </div>

  </div>

  <div class="col-xs-12 tours">
   
  </div>

  <div class="col-xs-12 tours">
   
  </div>   

 </div>
 

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `hidden-xs` class to your `preview-img` div

> http://getbootstrap.com/css/#responsive-utilities